# Linearize an OTA audio crossfader

Tags: analog, audio, pnp, linearity

I'm working on a voltage-controlled crossfader.

The schematic is taken from [this thread on the electro-music forum](https://electro-music.com/forum/topic-54633.html).

It's a simplified version of Thomas Henry's VC crossfader.

I've been experimenting with it on LTspice and breadboarding it.

[image: LTSPICE SCHEMATIC]

It works really well, I like the simplicity and the economy of components.

The only downside... it isn't linear.

[image: CFDR PLOT1]

Image above: Green trace is the CV input (triangular ±5V), the Purple trace is the audio output.

[image: CFDR PLOT2]

Image above: Green and red traces are the labc currents controlling the LM13700.

Could anyone with more experience than me (beginner really) imagine a simple and basic way to linearize those control currents?

Comment: Why the control currents need to be linear, what problem there is when they are not? Now I don't know how this specific crossfader works, but generally, volume controls are logarithmic, not linear, so maybe that's how the circuit should work, a linear control voltage having non-linear response.

Comment: Maybe try inputting two sinewaves at 20 Hz and 100 Hz but, make sure their amplitude doesn't cause clipping. It may paint a more linear picture because the one you have (lilac trace) looks badly distorted. Of course, there's every chance that it won't be more linearly crossfading!

Comment: Justme : Sure, the circuit is working as it should. For my intended application, I'd like to have more range in the 'overlap' zones between the two audio sources. Therefore the need for more linearity.

Comment: Andy aka: The audio inputs in that LTspice simulation are pure constant waveforms (one square / one sine) of the same amplitude, the circuit doesn't distort.

Comment: OK, it might be a long-shot but, try 100 ohm to 1 kohm resistors in the bases of Q3 and Q4. If it starts to look more linear try increasing them. Easy to try using your LTspice circuit.